# Deleting data that all users use but only for one user in Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to structure my data such that when someone adds a new product to the database, all users receive the new product in their list and therefore the new product appears on their screen.
But if a user decides to delete that product, they can delete it but only for themselves. Is there a Cloud Firestore sorting/ordering/filtering that I should be using to accomplish this?

I thought I could use something like the following:

```
final theProduct = Provider.of<Products>(context);

products = await firestore.collection('products').getDocuments()

for (product in products.documents) {
await firestore.collection('products').add({
'nameOfProduct': theProduct.nameOfProduct
});
}
```

But I get a document property error.

Maybe I need to go in one more collection and then try something? But I also need to be able to retrieve the data back using the userID of the signed in user..

Any hints/helpful links would be greatly appreciated.

---

So I think what I want to do is iterate through all documents within a collection and then document().collection('').add() something to each of their collection. Hopefully that sheds some more light on my problem.

Comment: you could try to save  the data in two collections `mydata` and  `public` and wen a user deletes data its only for the `mydata` collection and it remains in public where everyone can see it

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to those who commented. I found a way to implement this was to use the unique value that each product contains and add it to a list on a per user basis in Firestore. Then fetch that list from Firestore and filter out the corresponding products. No deleting necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Question : a user decides to delete that product, they can delete it but only for themselves

Answer: U can create list in user profile section where u can have all the product document ids & u can use that document id to fetch particular product details & when user click on delete button u can remove that particular document id from there collection

Im not sure what r u doing with sample code over there.

If u want to add data to database then use :

```
await Firestore().collection('Products').add({
  'nameOfProduct': theProduct.nameOfProduct,
});
```

this will generate document random id for your product.

To get data from particular id use :

```
DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = await Firestore().collection('Products').document('document').get();
```

then u can use that document snapshot to get data for particular key e.g.

```
documentSnapshot.data['Product Name']
```